# Show that the trajectory of the system move on a circle

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the dynamical system given by
$$\dot{x_1}=x_1^2-x_2^2, \qquad \dot{x_2}=2x_1x_2.$$
Show that the trajectories of the above system move along circles. Compute radius and center.

I have tried a few things, but no luck so far. There should be no need to compute trajectories.

Comment: You can improve this question by showing or summarizing the "few things" you've already tried.

Comment: Just to compare results, the structure of the right side terms should be well-known, and indeed if you set $z=x_1+ix_2$ you get $\dot z=z^2$. The solutions are inversions of lines, thus indeed circles (or again lines in some exceptional cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic circle reads $(x_1-a)^2+(x_2-b)^2=r^2$ and the tangent space is

$$
(x_1-a)\dot x_1 + (x_2-b)\dot x_2 = 0
$$

so

$$
(x_1-a)(x_1^2-x_2^2)+2(x_2-b)x_1x_2=0
$$

or

$$
x_1^3+x_1x_2^2-ax_1^2+ax_2^2-2bx_1x_2=0
$$

now if $a=0$ we have

$$
x_1(x_1^2+x_2^2-2bx_2)=0
$$

Attached a stream plot with two circular orbits $x_1^2+x_2^2-2bx_2=0$ for $b=1$ (red) and for $b=-1$ (blue).

[image]